# Replay pcap on local machine only

Tags: linux, tcpdump, pcap

RHEL 6.5.

I have a capture of UDP packets, generated this way:

```
tcpdump -nnXs 0 -i eth1 udp port 26477 and dst 233.86.230.111 -w ITCH.pcap
```

I've moved this file over to a dev VM, and want to replay it through my server for debugging.  My server does not (yet) have the capability to read pcaps directly, so I want to rebroadcast this via UDP.

However, I want the packets to both be sent and recieved on the same box.  That's because this VM is on the production network, and I don't want to flood the network.  I'm fine replaying these packets through the loopback interface (in fact, that's preferred).  I can configure my server to read from any mcast group/port, off of any interface.

Is there any way I can replay these packets so that they don't leave the local machine, and read them in my server?

`tcpreplay` won't work apparently because the packets won't be seen on the sending box.